# Interpreting $P(X | X\leq Y)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

In this case $X$ and $Y$ are independent discrete random variables greater than or equal to $1$.

I am trying to interpret $P(X | X \leq Y)$. Using the definition of conditional probability, you can get $P(X,X \leq Y)/P(X \leq Y)$.

In this case, what's the difference between $P(X, X \leq Y)$ and $P(X \leq Y)$? I am trying to break $P(X \leq Y)$ into its individual probabilities and I get:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} Pr((X = k, Y > k) \cup (X = k, Y = k))$$

which is similar to $P(X, X \leq Y)$. I am not sure where I am going wrong in this case.

Comment: I think we have to make clear what your notation means. Probability law $P$ is for events. What do you mean by $P(X, X \leq Y)$ (or even $P(X)$ alone) if $X$ is a random variable?

Comment: $P$ refers to the probability distribution of the random variable. So $P(X)$ refers to the probability distribution of the events of $X$. $P(X, X \leq Y)$ refers to the probability distribution of the events of X and X $\leq$ Y. I am a little unclear about the notation myself but the starting point is P(X | X $\leq$ Y).

Comment: Your notation is wrong. If you are asking about probability distribution (i.e. probability mass function, or PMF) of $X$, conditioned on $X\leqslant Y$, it is denoted as $p_X(x|X\leqslant Y)$

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are referring to the conditional distribution of $X$ given $X \leq Y$. This is often written as $Pr(X \in \cdot \mid X \leq Y)$ in some literature.

Taking advantage of the fact that $X$ is discrete, this conditional distribution is also discrete and is specified by the following conditional pmf

$$ p(x \mid X \leq Y)
:= Pr(X = x \mid X \leq Y)
= \frac{Pr(X = x, X \leq Y)}{Pr(X \leq Y)}
= \frac{Pr(X = x, x \leq Y)}{Pr(X \leq Y)}. $$

This is purely a definition for $p(x \mid X \leq Y)$, so you still need work with assertions to specify it. In our case, independence provides a simple answer:

$$ p(x \mid X \leq Y) = \frac{Pr(X = x)Pr(x \leq Y)}{Pr(X \leq Y)} $$

where the denominator is given by

$$ Pr(X\leq Y) = \sum_{x} Pr(X = x, X \leq Y) = \sum_{x} Pr(X = x)Pr(x \leq Y). $$

Finally, notice here that $Pr(X \leq Y)$ is just a number, while the conditional distribution of $X$ is a notion which is more complicated than just a number. This can be defined equally either by the conditional cdf $F(x) = Pr(X \leq x \mid X \leq Y)$ or by the law $B \mapsto Pr(X \in B \mid X \leq Y)$. Even the shorthand notation $Pr(X \in \cdot \mid X \leq Y)$ retains the symbol $\in \cdot$ in order to inform the reader that this is not just a number.

Answer (score 0):

If $P(X\mid X\le Y)$ stands for $P(X=i\mid X\le Y), \ i=0,\pm1,\pm2,\dots$ then

$$P(X=i\mid X\le Y)=\frac{P(X=i\ \cap\ X\le Y)}{P(X\le Y)}$$

where

$$P(X=i\ \cap X\le Y)=\sum_{j=i}^{\infty}P(X=i\ \cap Y=j)=P(X=i)\sum_{j=i}^{\infty}P(Y=j)$$

and

$$P(X\le Y)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{j=k}^{\infty}P(X=k\ \cap Y=j)=$$
$$=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}P(X=k)\sum_{j=k}P(Y=j).$$

So,

> $$P(X=i\mid X\le Y)=P(X=i)\frac{\sum_{j=i}^{\infty}P(Y=j)}{\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}P(X=k)\sum_{j=k}P(Y=j)}.$$